# Query taking too much time in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.1, query-performance

My table has 20 million records. my table contains two fields (empno,ename). empno column contains values but some ename column does not contain values. so i am trying to update the ename column using below block. i created index for empno column, but this below block running more than 10
hours (not finished)

```
create table index_test(empno integer,ename varchar(50))

create index ix_index_test on index_test(empno,ename)



DO $$
<<first_block>>
DECLARE
X RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR X IN(SELECT EMPNO FROM INDEX_TEST)
LOOP
UPDATE INDEX_TEST SET ENAME='Raja'||x.empno where empno=x.empno AND ENAME IS NULL;
END LOOP;
END first_block $$;
```

sample data

```
Empno     ENAME
15346070  Raja15346070
14208203
15392731
17419579
13287096
```

Comment: is there any wrong in index creation?

Comment: The index won't help - the problem is the inefficient and slow row-by-row processing you do through the loop.

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Doing million of single row updates in a loop is a sure way to bring any relational database down. You can do what you want with a single UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE index_test 
   SET ename = 'Raja'||empno 
WHERE ename IS NULL;
```

If only a small fraction of the rows contain a NULL value in the `ename` column then the following index might help:

```
create index on index_test (empno)
where ename is null;
```

But if you are going to update a substantial number of the total rows, no index will help. As a matter of fact, adding indexes might slow things down.